# Joined tables - AND WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined tables just like result here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

```
LastName    FirstName   OrderNo
Hansen      Ola         1
Hansen      Ola         2
Hansen      Ola         3
Pettersen   Kari        8
Pettersen   Kari        9
Svendson    Tove
```

How can I find the list of people (LastName, FirstName) that have both orders 1 and 2 associated with them.

Comment: Don't use w3schools, it's not a good resource, see: http://w3fools.com

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have told you to remove the second `WHERE`.

What they haven't said is that if you're looking for both records 1 and 2, you would need to use an `OR`, not an `AND`. Specifying `AND` would fail because the query would look for a single record that matches both criteria, which of course is impossible in this case.

So your `WHERE` clause should look like this:

```
WHERE OrderNo = 1 OR OrderNo = 2
```

Comment: OR works but no how i would like. I need to get record that has OrderNo = 1 AND OrderNo = 2. Both 1 and 2 values together. If I use OR it will return me records that has one of these values or two.

Comment: @user955399, if you want something very specific, please edit the question to list the exact outcome you want. _(preferably in the form of a table, just like table1 in your question)_

Comment: @user955399 - agreed; the question really was not clear that this was what you were wanting. To achieve this in a single query, you will need to completely change the way you've joined the tables. As things stand, you don't have a single record with both OrderNo=1 and =2; you have two records. It will be possible to rewrite the query to put both order numbers into the same record, but it's probably not a wise way to do things. It's far easier just to collect the two records that match and display/process them outside of SQL to suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the second WHERE

```
WHERE OrderNo = 1 OR OrderNo = 2
```

OR

```
WHERE OrderNo IN (1,2)
```

Comment: okay. I've removed my -1. :)  (what amazes me is that three separate answers all made the same mistake! they've all now been corrected, but there must have been some sort of collective blindness going on)

Answer (score 1):

First, don't write `WHERE` twice. You are only allowed one `WHERE` clause per [`SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Second, you can't have a row where `OrderNo = 1 AND OrderNo = 2`. It's impossible for both these to be true at the same time. Use `OR` instead of `AND`:

```
WHERE OrderNo = 1
OR OrderNo = 2
```

In this case you could just use [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
WHERE OrderNo IN (1, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking the full example (with explicit table.Field for readability):

```
Select persons.LastName, persons.FirstName, orders.OrderNo
FROM Persons
LEFT JOIN Orders order1 ON persons.P_Id=orders1.P_Id
LEFT JOIN Orders order2 ON persons.P_Id=orders2.P_Id
where (orders.OrderNo = 1 or orders.OrderNo = 2
```

It's important to be very explicit when working with joins so you (and developers after you) don't get confused. Not providing the table.Field will also throw and error if the two tables have a field with the same name.

**Update**

From comment on another response:

> OR works but no how i would like. I need to get record that has OrderNo = 1 AND OrderNo = 2. Both 1 and 2 values together. If I use OR it will return me records that has one of these values or two

If I am reading this correctly, you are only looking for Orders which are going to the repeat people (Person)? If that is the case then this will do the trick:

```
Select DISTINCT orders1.OrderNo, persons.LastName, persons.FirstName
FROM Persons 
LEFT JOIN Orders orders1 
  ON persons.P_ID = orders1.P_ID
LEFT JOIN Orders orders2 
  ON persons.P_ID = orders2.P_ID
Where orders1.P_ID = orders2.P_ID
```

If you only want the orders for a single, specific Person, that's a different query all together

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> WHERE OrderNo = 1
> AND WHERE OrderNo = 2
> ```

Your spec is very brief.

The relational equivalent of AND above could be `UNION` e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderNo = 1
UNION
SELECT * 
  FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderNo = 2;
```

Possibly the relational operator is divide i.e. return name of any person with both order numbers 1 and 2 e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LastName, FirstName
  FROM Orders AS O1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                   SELECT OrderNo
                     FROM (VALUES (1), (2)) AS Divisor (OrderNo)
                   EXCEPT
                   SELECT OrderNo
                     FROM Orders AS O2
                    WHERE O2.LastName = O1.LastName
                          AND O2.FirstName = O1.FirstName
                  );
```

But I rather suspect you meant logical OR rather than logical AND (I knew a business analyst who wrote sepcs with the word 'and' in natural language to mean logical OR e.g. "It could be this and it could be that") e.g.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Orders
 WHERE (OrderNo = 1 OR OrderNo = 2);
```

SQL has nice syntactic sugar for this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Orders
 WHERE OrderNo IN (1, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the names of the people who have both orders 1 and 2.

You could use this query:

```
SELECT LastName, FirstName 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE OrderNo IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY LastName, FirstName
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Note: I'm making the assumption that you won't have exact duplicate records, if you do you need to first eliminate duplicates.